# split each "record" on jqgrid to two rows

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a jqgrid that has a lot of information for each record.  It's causing a lot of horizontal scrolling and I'd like to avoid that.

I thought about using a subgrid, but every example I've seen for subgrid has the sub-info collapsed and I don't really want that.  I just want the 2nd row for each record to be indented a bit.

Is there a good way to handle this besides using a subgrid.  The other drawback to subgrid I've found is that it wants to load secondary data on the click to expand it.  I'd rather just have all of the data loaded on the initial grid load.

TIA